# How to retrieve the next key value pair in a json file with jq when I know the previous one

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file:

```js
{
   "entry1":"",
   "entry2":"",
   "entry3":"value3",
   "entry4":"value4",
   "entry5":"",
   "entry6":" ",
   "entry7":"",
   "entry8":"false"
}
```

I know the key value pair of the entry3 but not the next one (entry4 and value).
How can I access them?

For now, I'm stuck on the below command:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value == "value3") | .key, .value'
```

Comment: JSON spec does not guarantee ordering of key/value pairs in an object. So by definition `"entry4"` need not be immediately following `"entry3"`. Although arrays can contain an ordered list of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` once more (acting on the array) in which case you get numbers as indices in the `.key` field. Do your filtering with `select`, then increment the result `.key`, and fetch that item by direct indexing `.[n]`:

```bash
to_entries | .[
  to_entries[] | select(.value.value == "value3").key + 1
] | .key, .value
```

```
entry4
value4
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wtjIUuHGjUc)

Note that the entries in JSON objects semantically don't have an order, i.e. any other ordering would be considered the same object. `to_entries` merely returns the items in representation order, which is what you wanted to query, just be aware that this piece of information, strictly speaking, is not part of the data conveyed by the JSON input.

---

Edit:

> My goal is to retrieve the key values pairs for entry3 and entry4

In this case, you could slide through the array returned by `to_entries` with a window of two overlapping items, e.g. using `while(. != []; .[1:])[:2]`. Then, `select` as before but from the `first` item in that window, and eventually output the data from the `first` and `last` item:

```bash
to_entries | while(. != []; .[1:])[:2]
| select(first.value == "value3")
| first.key, first.value, last.key, last.value
```

```
entry3
value3
entry4
value4
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YwQN-7hgxWd)

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach:

```
to_entries
| range(0;length-1) as $n
| select( .[$n].key == "entry3" )
| .[$n:$n+2][]
| [.key, .value]
```

This produces

```
["entry3","value3"]
["entry4","value4"]
```

Tweak to taste.

Comment: It's not working from my side

Comment: I've verified it works using several versions of jq.  Have you tried putting the jq program in a file?

Comment: I tested from jqplay site, and it's not working, result is empty

Comment: It works on jqplay as shown here: https://jqplay.org/s/Oehcc4wqmh1