# How to retrieve the next key value pair with jq when I know the previous value only

Tags: json, jq

I would like to retrieve the next key value pair if I know the previous value one from the JSON file like below:

```js
{
   "metadata":{
      "secretSchema":"3.0",
      "tenant":"MyTenantName"
   },
   "globalSecrets":[
      {
         "secretName":"secretName1",
         "secretValue":"secretValue1"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName2",
         "secretValue":"secretValue2"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName3",
         "secretValue":"secretValue3"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName4",
         "secretValue":"secretValue4"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName5",
         "secretValue":"secretValue5"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName6",
         "secretValue":"secretValue6"
      },
      {
         "secretName":"secretName7",
         "secretValue":"secretValue7"
      }
   ]
}
```

I only know the value of the **secretValue5** and would like to retrieve the
**secretName5** value and the next one (**secretName6** and **secretValue6**)

I tried the following command:

```
.globalSecrets[] | to_entries | while(. != []; .[1:])[:2] | select(first.value == "secretValue5") | first.key, first.value, last.key, last.value
```

But the result is

```
secretValue
secretValue5
secretValue
secretValue5
```

The result expected is

```
secretName5
secretValue5
secretName6
secretValue6
```

I posted a similar question in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481826/how-to-retrieve-the-next-key-value-pair-in-a-json-file-with-jq-when-i-know-the-p/77495881#77495881) but with another JSON file with the above command and it's working fine, but not from the above JSON file.

Comment: Did you try this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77484449/5291015 and the jq play snippet seems to indicate that it works fine

Comment: You should perhaps delete this question, leave comments on the previous one (for the accepted answer) and ask for updates for your new JSON structure. Duplicating questions with no real answer value is not useful

Comment: Even though the topic is similar (this question is actually a derivative), the previous one was asking for the next key-value pair in an object, while this is about the next item in an array. To me, this is a substantial difference (not least regarding the question whether items of an object have an order at all), thus not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the [previous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77481931/2158479) which was about finding the next key-value pair in an object. In the current case, however, the question is about finding the next item in an array (which, in contrast to the previous case, has an explicit order), while the array items are objects, and the output is two values from the found object (rather than their key-value pairs). Thus, you don't need `to_entries`, and in consequence any reference to `.key` or `.value`. Just work directly on the array `.globalSecrets` and the fields of its items (`.secretName` and `.secretValue`):

```bash
.globalSecrets | while(. != []; .[1:])[:2]
| select(first.secretValue == "secretValue5")
| first.secretName, first.secretValue, last.secretName, last.secretValue
```

```
secretName5
secretValue5
secretName6
secretValue6
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9H10-d-pwRx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this quick solution, exactly what I need.